# Difference in neural activity of a thought vs. a memory

Tags: neuroscience, memory, neural-network, working-memory, short-term-memory

I want to understand the difference in neural activity between a "thought" and a "memory impression". Is it a "thought" while the neural activity is present in working memory and then an "impression" once the data is transferred to long term store? Or is a thought not technically stored in the brain yet, and once awareness is brought to it, the observation of the thought saves the initial impression in working memory?

Comment: This is one of the nice questions! I "think" thoughts *are* memories floating in a certain way.